# How the cipher negotiation in snmpv3 will happen?

Tags: security, aes, snmp, sha, privacy

I'm working on snmpv3. In the RFC and internet I haven't seen any documentation regarding how the encryption and hashing algorithms exchanged between the entities. I wonder will there be any cipher negotiation happens in SNMPv3 or both parties should agree upon a specific set of algorithms prior to the communication and use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder whether you are reading the proper RFC documents. For SNMP v3 there is no cipher negotiation at all. You have to know exactly how a device is configured so as to manage it.

It is not something like HTTP over SSL.

Comment: In SNMPV3 we have a provision of chosing the hashing and encryption algorithms. So that all the SNMP traffic can be encrypted and authenticated using those algorithms. My question is in this case will the both parties agree upon a specific hash and encryption algorithm prior to the communication, if not then how?